# PDFBOX 2.0: How to process subStream

Tags: pdfbox

I have a substream from Xobject which I want to process using PDFBOX 2.0

```
Iterable<COSName> cosNames = pdResources.getXObjectNames();

for (COSName cosname : cosNames) {
    PDXObject xobject = pdResources.getXObject(cosname);
    COSStream stream = xobject.getCOSObject();
}
```

I want to process "stream", I am extending PDFStreamEngine, and I only find processPage function, looks like in PDFBOX 1.8 they had a function to process substreams:

```
processSubStream(PDPage aPage, PDResources resources, COSStream cosStream)
```

Is it possible to do the same in PDFBOX 2.0?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe processChildStream or showForm is what you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tilman Posted in the comment, you can use processChildStream  (a protected method) or showForm (public method, but you need to initialize the current page first)